# minizip-asm extract function takes forever to execute

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fetch an AES encrypted password protected zip file from a google storage and extract a csv file from it. I am using google cloud functions for it with node 6.
I've tried using `minizip-asm.js` library to extract the file. It works intermittently. I am a newbie when it comes to node so would really appreciate some help :).
Here's the relevant piece of code which might help. Could someone help me figure out what's going wrong here.

```
exports.processFile = (event, callback) => {
const file = event.data;
const filename = file.name;
const projectId = "abc1234";
const bucketName = "abc_reports";

const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = Storage({
    projectId: projectId
});
const folder = storage.bucket(bucketName);
const minizip = require('minizip-asm.js');







if (file.metageneration === '1' && filename.match(".zip") != null) {
    // metageneration attribute is updated on metadata changes.
    // on create value is 1
    console.log(`File ${file.name} uploaded.`);






      folder.file(filename).download().then(function(data) {
        console.log('Download of file complete');




            //create csv file 
            var csvName = filename.split(".zip")[0] + ".csv"

          var mz = new minizip(data[0]);
       console.log(data[0]);
            console.log(mz.list());

            var extract = mz.extract(mz.list()[0].filepath,{
              password: 'ABC@123'
            })
            console.log("extracted");





        //write unzipped contents to file

        folder.file(csvName).save(extract, function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log("unzipped csv");
                    }
                else console.log("Error in saving csv : "+err);
                });

       }); 
      });
}

callback(null, 'Success!');
};
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please can you share the entirety of the code for your Cloud Function? Are you seeing an error message or just long execution times? How large are the zip files?

Comment: @ChristopherP Thanks for reverting. I've posted the complete code now. There are no errors in the log, just no further execution. The files are around 100KB in size.

Comment: @ChristopherP Have edited to add information on the encryption of the zip file. It's an AES encrypted zip file.

Comment: Sorry, there is not even "timeOut error" on the logs? May you provide the exactly link or version of "minizip-asm.js" in order to try to reproduce your issue?